# Is there a difference between full dress and dress uniform when speaking about the army?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, confusables

I'm so confused when it comes to these two words. The dictionaries offer the same meanings and when I tried to google the images they seemed to look the same to me.

Comment: They normally have the same meaning. However, **full dress** would imply that *all of one's awards and decorations should be worn.* Sometimes the decisions of which to display is left to the soldier's discretion.

Comment: As with all terminology questions, it is highly likely the more reliable answer will come from a field expert, not a language expert. How professionals or scholars use a term often differs from the way the general public uses a term. You have not indicated whose usage you seek.

Answer (score 2):

When I was in the US Army we referred to our dress greens as *dress* and our dress blues as *full dress*.  We wore our dress blues for ceremonial occasions (civilian counterpart would be your Sunday best suit) and our dress greens for day-to-day office-type work (civilian counterpart would be an everyday suit) and our battle dress uniforms for combat training or everyday-non-office work (civilian counterpart would be jeans and a t-shirt or hunting gear).  There is also a mess dress uniform worn for very formal events, usually in the evening (civilian counterpart would be a tuxedo).

However, the US Army has phased out the dress greens (as well as dress whites which were only worn in some tropical locations) and now there is a singe dress blue uniform for anything more formal than everyday-non-office-work and less formal than a mess dress event.

Here's some background provided by wiki:

> Full dress uniform is a special military uniform reserved for parade
>   or other ceremonial occasions. Prior to World War I (1914–18) most
>   armies of the world retained uniforms of this type that were usually
>   more colorful and elaborate than the ordinary duty ("undress") or the
>   increasingly drab active service ("field") uniforms.
>
> The British and United States armies were dependent upon voluntary
>   recruiting and found that a smart dress served to attract recruits and
>   improve morale amongst those already serving. The British regimental
>   system fostered numerous distinctions amongst different units.
>
> Even the mainly conscript armies of continental Europe retained many
>   of the colourful features that had evolved during the nineteenth
>   century, for reasons of national and unit pride. Thus, in 1913 most
>   French soldiers wore red trousers and kepis as part of their full
>   dress, the majority of British foot regiments retained scarlet tunics
>   for parade and off duty ("walking out"), the German Army was
>   characterised by Prussian blue, the Russian by dark green, et cetera.
>
> There were usually exceptions to each of these rules, often
>   distinguishing elite units. Thus German cuirassiers wore white full
>   dress, British rifle regiments a very dark green known as rifle green,
>   French mountain troops large berets and light blue trousers and so on.
>   The U.S. Army with its smart but relatively sober "dress blues" was an
>   exception, with cavalry, artillery and infantry being distinguished
>   only by the different branch colors.
>
> After World War I most full dress uniforms disappeared. Many of the
>   Imperial or Royal regimes that had taken a particular pride in the
>   retention of colorful traditional uniforms had been overthrown and
>   their republican, fascist, or communist successors had little
>   incentive to retain old glories. Elsewhere cost and disillusion with
>   the "peacock" aspects of old fashioned soldiering had a similar
>   effect, except for ceremonial guard units and such limited exceptions
>   as officers' evening or off-duty uniforms.
>
> Modern armies are characterised by simple and drab coloured dress even
>   for ceremonial occasion, with the exceptions noted above. However a
>   general trend towards replacing conscript armies with long serving
>   professionals has had, as a side effect, a reversion to dress uniforms
>   that combine smartness with some traditional features. Thus the U.S.
>   Army announced in 2006 that uniforms of modern cut but in the
>   traditional dark and light blue colours will become universal issue,
>   replacing the previous grey/green service dress.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_dress